# Cannot find static files on django ec2 instance

Tags: django, static, amazon-ec2

I am running a bitnami-djangostack 1.4 ubuntu 12.04 AMI.

I am trying to simply serve a .jpg file from an html page.

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    # static stuff:
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

This is the relevant portion of my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/bitnami/statictest/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/static_root/images',
    '/home/bitnami/statictest',
    '/home/bitnami/statictest/images',
    '/home/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static_root',
)
```

I have scp'ed a simple jpeg image to the statictest/ location but when I navigate to my {url}/static/image.jpg I get the following message:

> The requested URL /static/image.jpg was not found on this server.

Is there anything else I need to do to be able to serve this image?

Comment: If this is a production environment (considering you're using static_root) you should setup your server to serve static files

Comment: Its a live server that I'm using for testing/prototyping. What should do to make sure that it can serve static files?